# How to rotate an image and it stop it randomly on multiple of 18 °

Tags: android, animation, random, rotation, automatic-ref-counting

How to rotate an image and it stop it randomly on multiple of 18 °.
I use these lines of code to make turn a spinning top and that works very well. I would want that it stops on multiple of 18 °, that I have to add? Thank you.

```java
float deg = toupie1300.getRotation() 
            + BASE_ROTATION_DEGREES + ((float) Math.random() * 360F);

toupie1300.animate().rotation(deg).setDuration(DURATION)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

Comment: 360 / 18 = 20.  Pick a number in the range `0 .. 19` and multiply by 18.

Comment: Can you explicite better? Where I pick a number?

Comment: You will need to pick an integer, so use `Random.nextInt(20)`.

Comment: Can you give me the line of code completed? I am new with random!

Comment: Read the documentation for `java.util.Random`.  If I write the code for you, then you will not learn as much and will have to come back here again and again.  "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime."